# configuring django settings after moving to another directory?

Tags: python, django, django-settings

my django project structure is shown below,

```
.
├── myapp
│   ├── apps
│   │   └── __init__.py
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── settings.py
│   ├── urls.py
│   └── wsgi.py
├── manage.py
└── tests
    └── test_config.py
```

from where I moved settings file to form the below structure.

```
.
├── myapp
│   ├── apps
│   │   └── __init__.py
│   ├── config
│   │   ├── __init__.py
│   │   ├── settings.py
│   │   ├── urls.py
│   │   └── wsgi.py
│   └── __init__.py
├── manage.py
└── tests
    └── test_config.py
```

so I changed my `wsgi.py`

```
import os

from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application

os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "myapp.config.settings")

application = get_wsgi_application()
```

and and my `manage.py`

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import os
import sys

if __name__ == "__main__":
    os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "myapp.config.settings")

    print "settings!!"

    from django.core.management import execute_from_command_line

    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
```

now when I run the django shell with`./manage.py shell` I get this error, the traceback posted below.

```
Python 2.7.10 (default, Oct 14 2015, 16:09:02) 
[GCC 5.2.1 20151010] on linux2
Django 1.9.2
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 5, in <module>
  File "/home/marty/.virtualenvs/seventeen/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line 17, in setup
    configure_logging(settings.LOGGING_CONFIG, settings.LOGGING)
  File "/home/marty/.virtualenvs/seventeen/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 55, in __getattr__
    self._setup(name)
  File "/home/marty/.virtualenvs/seventeen/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 41, in _setup
    % (desc, ENVIRONMENT_VARIABLE))
ImproperlyConfigured: Requested setting LOGGING_CONFIG, but settings are not configured. You must either define the environment variable DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE or call settings.configure() before accessing settings
```

what is the problem here? how do I fix this?

thanks

Comment: I just created a Django project with an identical structure to the one in your question, and I can run manage.py shell fine. Could you try deleting the *.pyc files?

Answer (score 6):

myapp is not in PYTHONPATH, so myapp.config.settings is not a valid module.

Before the os.environ, add the following lines:

```
import sys
sys.path.append('path/to/dir/of/myapp')
```

Comment: just to make sure: if you have "/home/username/myprojects/myapp" then sys.path.append("/home/username/myprojects/")?

Comment: Splendid! Nice tip